# "Joomla is not defined" error when logged in - Pagination

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, custom-component, pagination

Hi we have 2 different custom componenets running on a website (they aren't loaded together, just have the same issue) and they have pagination.
We are finding that when clicking on the pagination an error appears in the console saying "Joomla is not defined"

However this problem only happens when a user is logged in. If you are viewing the website as a guest the pagination works.
I have looked at the source code and can only find this script tag when NOT logged in, if I am logged in, it disappears

```
<script type="application/json" class="joomla-script-options new">{"csrf.token":"b45d9db1708f046a81ec5746ba26ed7c","system.paths":{"root":"","base":""},"system.keepalive":{"interval":840000,"uri":"\/component\/ajax\/?format=json"}}</script>
```

I have tried a couple of solutions (eg adding JHtml::_('behavior.framework');) to the components code but nothing works.

Would anyone know whats going on? It did work before, I don't however know when it stopped.

Comment: Is this a console log error or a PHP error?

Comment: Sorry for not defining, it was a console error